# Video is not playing completely and finishing in between

Tags: android, video, media-player, surfaceview

I have created an application in which video plays in a loop from the playlist one by one. I have used surfaceview to run the videos. The problem is that in starting video was playing fine but after long time, video started playing incompletely and finishing in between.

Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Watch the logcat output when it misbehaves; maybe there will be some clue there.

Comment: I am getting this error in logcat.                                               E/MediaPlayer(1911): error (1, -2147483648)